# Pandas groupby and then sort based on groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of news articles and their associated concepts and sentiment (NLP detected) which I want to group by 2 fields: the Concept and the Source. A simplification is following:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'concept_label': [1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1],
                      'source_uri': ['A','B','A','A','A','C','C','C'],
                      'sentiment_article': [0.05,0.15,-0.3,-0.2,-0.5,-0.6,-0.3,-0.4]})


    concept_label  source_uri   sentiment_article
    1              A            0.05
    1              B            0.15
    2              A            -0.3
    2              A            -0.2
    3              A            -0.5
    1              C            -0.6
    1              C            -0.3
    1              C            -0.4
```

So I basically would want to know for the concept "Coronavirus" how often each news outlet writes about the topic and what the mean sentiment of the article is. The above df would then look like this:

```
                               mean     count
concept_label    source_uri      
3                A             -0.50    1
2                A             -0.25    2
1                A             0.050    1
1                B             0.150    1
1                C             -0.43    3
```

I am able to do the grouping with the following code (df is the pandas dataframe I'm using, concept_label is the concept, and source_uri is the news outlet):

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['concept_label','source_uri'])
df_grouped['sentiment_article'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

This works just fine and gives me the values I need, however I want the groups with the highest aggregate number of "count" to be at the top. The way I tried to do that is by changing it to the following:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(['concept_label','source_uri'])
df_grouped['sentiment_article'].agg(['mean', 'count']).sort_values(by=['count'], ascending=False)
```

However even though this sorts by the count, it breaks up the groups again. My result currently looks like this:

```
                               mean     count
concept_label    source_uri      
3                A             -0.50    1
1                A             0.050    1
1                B             0.150    1
2                A             -0.25    2
1                C             -0.43    3
```

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) in particular a sampla of your data?

Comment: I added a sample to explain the problem. If it's not sufficient please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by `it breaks up the groups again`?

Comment: The grouping by concept_label is lost. As you can see in the final example, the number 1 is not grouped anymore. The sorting on count is done on row level, not on group level.

Comment: Can you include your desired result?

Comment: The desired result is the second data example in the description. Where it says "The above df would then look like this:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is the nicest answer, but I found a way to do it.

I grouped the total list first and saved the total count per concept_label as a variable that I then merged with the existing dataframe. This way I can just sort on that column and secondary on the actual count.

```
#adding count column to existing table
df_grouped = df.groupby(['concept_label'])['concept_label'].agg(['count']).sort_values(by=['count'])
df_grouped.rename(columns={'count':'concept_count'}, inplace=True)
df_count = pd.merge(df, df_grouped, left_on='concept_label', right_on='concept_label')

#sorting
df_sentiment = df_count.groupby(['concept_label','source_uri','concept_count'])['sentiment_article'].agg(['mean', 'count']).sort_values(by=['concept_count','count'], ascending=False)
```